# How do I switch profiles in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android, profiles

Is there any way to switch Chrome profiles while using the Chrome mobile phone app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to change Chrome profiles on Android/iOS as per Google Chrome Help [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en-GB&oco=0).

**But**, you can use apps like *Parallel Space* to have multiple chrome profiles.

Answer (score 6):

The only option for the time of writing this answer is to install addtional Chrome app from the above list: Chrome Stable, Beta, Dev, and Canary and login with a different google account

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip, works like a charm

Answer (score 5):

I figured out how to do it.
Go to settings on your android phone,
Then select Chrome and "Clear All Data".

When you switch on Chrome again, you can find an option to select a Primary account. Then you can select the account you want.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem. I was able to solve it by downloading the Chrome Beta app from the Play store.

You can then sign into one account via the beta app, and leave the other signed into the regular Chrome instance.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement [Amrita's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/236675/44325), you do:

1. Open Android phone settings.
2. Go to **Apps**.

   [image: Step 2]
3. Find and select **Chrome** to open *App info*.

   [image: Step 3]
4. Click on **Storage** to view *storage details*.

   [image: Step 4]
5. Click on **Manage Storage** to manage the storage.

   [image: Step 5]
6. Click on **Clear all data** to wipe account details from the browser.

   [image: Step 6]
7. Relaunch Chrome, Accept & Continue.

   [image: Step 7]
8. Select desired account from the drop-down and click **Yes, I'm in**.

   [image: Step 8 - 1]
   [image: Step 8 - 2]
   [image: Step 8 - 3]

Answer (score 0):

There is supposed to be:

If you open Chrome on Android, Menu, Settings, and select your account.

But this just takes you on an endless loop.

I wish changing your user on the phone settings would also change all your apps to log in as that user.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh. The closest I got was removing the account I didn't currently want to use, but then it took some finagling to get the account I wanted to use working properly. Very frustrating.